# Should I create a new answer to a community wiki checklist or edit an existing one?

Tags: discussion

There's a [very popular unanswered (but closed after this meta question was written) community wiki question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5119633/403455) that isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, but I am glad it's there.

I would like to add one or two items to "the" checklist, but I'm wondering how it should be done:

1. Create a new answer
2. Pick the answer with the most votes and add my new items to it
3. Add a comment to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those options are the correct way to approach that kind of question.

There was a point where these questions were allowed on Stack Overflow, but no longer.

The question you've referenced (and questions like it) are list questions, and we do not maintain list questions.

The proper thing to do in these situations is to vote to close as "Not Constructive".

If there isn't enough traction on the question to get it closed, then flag the question for moderator attention and we'll close it.